# Can't figure out this query

Tags: sql, ms-access

New to MS-Access and SQL. I have a table containing several fields and I am trying to create a query that will return records that meet a particular criteria. I am trying to write it in SQL.

The table is something like this. 3 columns labeled TxnID, TagNum, and Plate. The TxnID field contains all unique numbers. the TagNum and Plate fields contain duplicate numbers and blank records, which I listed as BLANK here but irl they are Null. There are actually more fields and millions of records, but these 3 fields are the ones needed for the query. FYI, I changed the numbers listed so as not to expose any personal info.

```
TxnID           TagNum          Plate
55116236301 403016275   EDT5104
56358456892 403072801   GLY7097
55971408561 403072801   GLY7097
55744617717 403072801   GLY7097
56358641191 BLANKxxxx       GLY7097
56071667010 403072801   GLY7097
56612568234 403072801   GLY7097
56229149821 403072801   GLY7097
56071570614 BLANKxxxx       GLY7097
56229178080 403072801   GLY7097
56612608166 403072801   GLY7097
```

I want the query to return only records where TagNum is blank and Plate is populated IF in other transactions TagNum is populated and Plate is populated. Essentially I want to find records where we expect a specific TagNum and specific Plate because we see that in other transactions, but we only get a Plate.

I've tried several different ways but my limited experience is hurting me here. I tried a COUNT((IIF...AS... in the SELECT statement because ultimately I want to count the number of occurrences. I tried putting it together in a WHERE clause. No success.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Edit the question and clarify what the result set should be.

Answer (score 0):

```
select *
from table t1
where tagnum = 'BLANK' and exists(select * from table t2 where t2.Plate = t1.Plate and t2.tagnum <> 'BLANK')
```

Answer (score 0):

Consider:

```
select *
from mytable t
where 
    (TagNum is null)
    and exists (
        select 1
        from mytable t1
        where t1.Plate = t.Plate and t1.TagNum is not null
    )
```

This will pull out records where `TagNum` is null and for which another record exists with the same `Plate` and a non-null `TagNum`.

Answer (score 0):

GMB's and Blindy's answers both do what you've asked.  I am expanding on the answer and adding a column that returns the TagNum that was found:

```
select t1.*, t2.tagnum
from table t1
inner join (
   select t.tagnum, t.plate
   from table t
   where t.tagnum is not null
   group by t.tagnum, t.plate
) t2 on t2.plate=t1.plate
where t1.tagnum is null
```

This could easily become an update statement if that is your end goal:
**dangerous and untested**

```
update t1
set tagnum = t2.tagnum
from table t1
inner join (
   select t.tagnum, t.plate
   from table t
   where t.tagnum is not null
   group by t.tagnum, t.plate
) t2 on t2.plate=t1.plate
where t1.tagnum is null
```

All of what I've written presumes and depends on each plate having only 1 tagnum.  If there isn't a 1-to-1 relationship then this answer should be deleted.

Answer (score 0):

This SQL will show the blank records and the value that should be there:

```
SELECT Table1.TxnID, Table1.TagNum AS isnull, Table1.Plate, Table1_1.TagNum AS Shouldbe
FROM Table1 INNER JOIN Table1 AS Table1_1 ON Table1.Plate = Table1_1.Plate
GROUP BY Table1.TxnID, Table1.TagNum, Table1.Plate, Table1_1.TagNum
HAVING (((Table1.TagNum) Is Null) AND ((Table1_1.TagNum) Is Not Null));
```

[image]

Tested with your data in Access 2016. You should be able to cut and paste the query above directly into an Access Query